# Passing method of a constructed object to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The code below would work in case of regular functions but it doesn't work in case of object methods.

I'm getting the following error:

```
  return this.anotherService.get1(start, end);
              ^
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'anotherService' of undefined
```

How do I rewrite the code to make `getTransactions` a general helper function executing different methods passed as arguments?

```
class Service {
  constructor(arg1) {
    this.anotherService= new AnotherService(arg1);
  }

  getMethod1(start, end) {
    return this.anotherService.get1(start, end);
  }

  getMethod2(start, end) {
    return this.anotherService.get2(start, end);
  }
} 

function getTransaction1(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  let service = new Service(arg1);
  getTransactions(arg2, arg3, service.getMethod1);
};

function getTransaction2(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  let service = new Service(arg1);
  getTransactions(arg2, arg3, service.getMethod2);
};

function getTransactions(arg2, arg3, func) {
  let start = ......;
  let end = ........;
  func(start, end).then(data => {
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(console.log);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Function#bind` to handle that:

```
function getTransaction1(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  let service = new Service(arg1);
  getTransactions(arg2, arg3, service.getMethod1.bind(service));
  // -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

function getTransaction2(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  let service = new Service(arg1);
  getTransactions(arg2, arg3, service.getMethod2.bind(service));
  // -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

[`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to be the object you pass to `bind`. (You can also pass additional arguments to `bind`, but that's not relevant here.)

---

Or, of course, you can create `getMethod1` and `getMethod2` within your constructor using fat arrow functions, which get a lexical `this` binding:

```
class Service {
  constructor(arg1) {
    this.anotherService= new AnotherService(arg1);
    this.getMethod1 = (start, end) => {
        return this.anotherService.get1(start, end);
    };
    this.getMethod2 = (start, end) => {
        return this.anotherService.get2(start, end);
    };
  }
}
```

...in which case you don't have to change `getTransaction1` and `getTransaction2` at all.

---

Side note: Function *declarations* (what you're using with `getTransaction1` and `getTransaction2`) aren't statements, and so they aren't terminated with semicolons.

Comment: right, I forgot this simple useful JavaScript trick.  not for the first time :)